Convertir array de una tabla SQL SERVER
por favor su apoyo estoy queriendo realizar de mi tabla convertir en  json establecido como esto
[
    {
     name: ''Polizas Semanal'',
     data: [12,50,20,40,60,120]
     } ,
    {
    name: ''Poliza Anual'',
    data: [122,501,202,401,610,1120]
    }
 ]

en mi tabla tengo estos datos que la columna [615_num_pol_pasiv] es la Poliza Semanal  y  [616_num_pol_pasiv] es la Poliza Anual
create table #P 
(
rfec date,rfecname varchar(250),[615_num_pol_pasiv] float null,[616_num_pol_pasiv] float null
)
insert into #P values('2023-07-31','Jul-23',5,3)
insert into #P values('2023-08-31','Aug-23',1,2)
insert into #P values('2023-09-30','Sep-23',10,15)


select 'name' = rfecname ,
       'data' = [615_num_pol_pasiv]

from #sss
for json PATH

Estoy realizando así pero no tengo el mismo resultado su apoyo por favor

Estás trabajando con algún lenguaje de programación? Lo estás haciendo en SQL únicamente?

@Rodrigo en angular pero como va ser dinamico por consultas quisiera que ya todo valla desde SQL SERVER

Probablemente te sirva este enlace de Microsoft Learn

@Rodrigo si justo hice con JSON PATH pero ahora donde dice name quisiera colocar si la columna dice [615_num_pol_pasiv] colocarle Poliza Semanal y si la columna [616_num_pol_pasiv]Poliza Anual

De dónde salen los números, "[12, 50, 20, 40..." etc, si no se ven por ningún lado en la tabla.

@jachguate ahí edite y coloque mi tabla esos numero que puse fue un ejemplo

y porque no hace la transformacion que vos queres el back?

Se espera que los datos de ejemplo sean congruentes. Si muestras que la tabla tiene 1, 2, 3 y el resultado que esperas tiene 1, 2, 3, se entiende lo que quieres. Pero si la tabla tiene 7, 10, 24 y esperas 52, 14, 81, o explicas como llegar de A a B, o mejor corrijes tus ejemplos, para que se entienda bien. Yo sigo sin ver cómo llegar a la salida que esperas con la edición que hiciste.

Para construir una salida JSON como la que esperas, debes:

Formar los arreglos de enteros por ti mismo, pues el soporte para JSON del motor no genera arreglos de valores. Mi recomendación es valerte de la función string_agg(). Por ejemplo, esta consulta:
  select '[' + STRING_AGG(cast(cast([615_num_pol_pasiv] as int) as varchar(20)), ',') + ']' 
    from #P

Va a devolver como resultado:
[5,1,10]


Luego, necesitas una consulta ad-hoc que te devuelva dos registros, uno para cada tipo de póliza del resultado final. Esto lo puedes conseguir con un CTE dónde hace las unión de dos consultas donde en cada una colocas el nombre del tipo de póliza y el arreglo formado en el paso anterior:

Finalmente, sobre este CTE haces la consulta final y aplicas la cláusula for json path para que forme la salida final.


Poniendo todo junto, sobre la tabla temporal que creas en la pregunta, quedaría algo como:
with
X as (
select   'Polizas semanal' as name
       , (select '[' + STRING_AGG(cast(cast([615_num_pol_pasiv] as int) as varchar(20)), ',') + ']' from #P) as data
union all
select   'Poliza Anual' as name
       , (select '[' + STRING_AGG(cast(cast([616_num_pol_pasiv] as int) as varchar(20)), ',') + ']' from #P) as data
)
select *
  from X
   for json path;

Esto devuelve como salida:
[{"name":"Polizas semanal","data":"[5,1,10]"},{"name":"Poliza Anual","data":"[3,2,15]"}]

dbfiddle
OJO: La salida que muestras como ejemplo es JSON mal formado, no he aplicado ninguna transformación adicional, pues supongo que quieres JSON bien formado. Si lo necesitas realmente como está en el ejemplo, puedes aplicar sustitución de cadenas sobre este resultado.

sustitución te refieres a replace cierto ?

si, la sustitución de cadenas se hace con la función replace.
